# How can I access to text data (value) of feature importance from a traiend model on Vertex AI with Python

Tags: google-ai-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am working on Predictive Modeling with AutoML on Vertex AI and got the trained model. I checked its feature importance Graphically at Model Tab on Vertex AI, and then I want to have its text data of feature importance with the below code, but can only see it and can not get each of items as value.

------------------------ Python Code

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1 as aiplatform2
api_endpoint = 'us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com'
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint} # api_endpoint is required for client_options
client_model = aiplatform2.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
project_id = 'this is my project id'
location = 'us-central1'
model_id = 'my trained id'
model_name = f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id}'

list_eval_request = aiplatform2.types.ListModelEvaluationsRequest(parent=model_name)
list_eval = client_model.list_model_evaluations(request=list_eval_request)
list_eval.model_evaluations
```

------------------------ Get this just visually on Notebook

```
[name: "projects/*********/locations/us-central1/models/*********/evaluations/*********"
metrics_schema_uri: "gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/modelevaluation/regression_metrics_1.0.0.yaml"
metrics {
  struct_value {
    fields {
      key: "meanAbsoluteError"
      value {
        number_value: 2863.7043
      }
    }
    fields {
      key: "meanAbsolutePercentageError"
      value {
        number_value: 197.63817
      }
```

------------------------ Question

How can I access to the "key" and its "value".
Example key: "meanAbsoluteError" / value : number_value: 2863.7043

Answer (score 0):

I get it like this

```
for a in list_eval.model_evaluations[0].metrics:
    b = str(list_eval.model_evaluations[0].metrics[a])
    v_str = a + ' : ' + b
    print(v_str)

rootMeanSquaredLogError : 1.2712421
rootMeanSquaredError : 26191.564
rSquared : 0.31798086
meanAbsoluteError : 5698.832
meanAbsolutePercentageError : 262.9534
```

"metrics" is simply a dictionary